# Are there passages in the synoptic gospels that could be used to support faith alone?

Tags: catholicism, bible, justification

I am wondering if there passages in the synoptic gospels that could be used to support faith alone?
I know there are some which seem to be in contrast to faith alone like the sheep and the goats.

Comment: Why have you tagged this "Catholicism"? You are asking a question about something that Catholics don't believe in.

Comment: Probably it is understood, but your question as phrased is unclear.  You probably mean "... could be used to support [salvation by] faith alone."